# Fill a table with sorted images

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, sorting

I just started to learn swift and am having some difficulties in this task.
I have 15 pictures in the assets  also have a table with two sections.
Need to fill in the cells with sorted picture.
Cell Example (.textLabel = nameImage + image )
The first section should have pictures from the 1st number to the 7th.
The second section should be from 8th to 15th.

This needs to be implemented in different files.
In one file only structures with properties.
In another, filling tables with sorted pictures.
My weakness is that I do not know how to fully implement it.
I created two structures. But I do not know what to do next

**Struct.swift**

```
import Foundation
struct imageOneSection {
    var titleImageOneSec:String
    var numImageOneSec: Int

    init(titleImageOneSec:String, numImageOneSec) {
        self.titleImageOneSec = titleImageOneSec
        self.numImageOneSec = numImageOneSec
    }
}

struct imageTwoSection {
    var titleImageTwoSec:String
    var numImageTwoSec: Int

    init(titleImageTwoSec:String, numImageTwoSec) {
        self.titleImageTwoSec = titleImageTwoSec
        self.numImageTwoSec = numImageTwoSec
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding images or text in table view cell? What type is your content?

Comment: Content is the text (image name) and the image itself on the side

Comment: You don't have any view code in your examples above. It seems like you are expecting people here to write your code for you, rather than helping you with a problem with your code. Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. And read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The second parameter of each of your `init`s is missing it's type. E.g.: `init(titleImageTwoSec:String, numImageTwoSec: Int)`

Comment: I think i need to assign a number to a picture and sort it by that. But if this parameter is not needed, then it is possible without it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only one struct and set multidimensional array, where one array would be set of images from 1 to 7 and another from 8 to 15. In the file where your adding content to your cell you can create:

```
let data: [[imageOneSection]] = [[imageOneSection.init(titleImageOneSec: imageName), numImage), ...], 
                                 [imageOneSection.init(titleImageOneSec: imageName, numImage), ...]]
```

Then for your table view methods add:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     // init your cell
     cell.addContent (data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
}
```

In your cell class add:

```
 func addContent (data: imageOneSection) {
      yourTextLabel.text = data.titleImageOneSec + "\(data. numImageOneSec)"
      yourImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: data.titleImageOneSec)
 }
```

Hope this will help you.